# In this situation, why is normal force not equal to $mg$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

[image: sloppy drawing of a diagram for a physics problem]

I know that normal force doesn't equal $mg$ on inclines due to the axes being changed, but why would it not be equal to $mg$ in this situation? The question this diagram is based on doesn't mention that the block isn't resting on the surface, nor does it mention if it does. If there's a force acting on an object with a positive $y$-component at an angle, does that mean the normal force is based on that instead?

In other words, if normal force is supposed to be the force that acts on an object in order to keep it from passing through another surface, I don't see how the y-component of the external force in this situation relates to that description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the normal force were equal to $mg$ then the $y$ component of acceleration would be non-zero. The block would accelerate upwards.

Answer (score 0):

It's not $mg$ simply because you've indicated that there is another force pulling the block upwards at some angle $\theta$.

$$F_{N}=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      mg-F\sin(\theta) & F\sin(\theta)\leq mg \\
      0 & F\sin(\theta)\geq mg \\
\end{array} 
\right.$$